Bus separation in the circuit
There is a circuit in which the bus comes with 4 values. How can this bus be split in half into different repetitive circuits?

When trying to repeat as in the picture, it gives an error on another sheet where the connection is taking place:

Main.SchDoc Compiler Net OUT3 has only one pin (Pin XS1-69)
Main.SchDoc Compiler Net OUT4 has only one pin (Pin XS1-70)

